# Howto assign a XAML object to a property (.NET35, XAML2006)

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

Inside my XAML I have two custom components:

```
<gui:CustomerBrowser x:Name="browser" CustomerDetailView="???" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
<gui:CustomerDetails x:Name="details" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

I like to assign the second component to a property of the first component but I don't get it. What will the `CustomerDetailView` attribute need to contain?

The type of `CustomerDetailView` is the interface `ICustomerView` which the other component `CustomerDetails` implements. Using: VS2010, .NET3.5, XAML2006.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I pretty much expected WPF 3.5 to be used, you could just try a normal binding in that case:

```
CustomerDetailsView="{Binding ElementName=details}"
```

*(In .NET 4 you could use [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx):)*

```
CustomerDetailsView="{x:Reference details}"
```

Comment: `x:Reference` needs XAML2009 / .NET4 as it seems. But I have to stick to .NET 3.5 (VS 2010).

Comment: If you use a version other than the most current you sould make that clear in the tags (and possibly question). Have you tried a binding (see updated answer).

Comment: There is no XAML2006 tag but I added information to the question.

Comment: @H.B., .NET 4 supports `x:Reference`, but VS2010 doesn't (the XAML compiler doesn't support it)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Exactly because it is a .NET 4 feature the 3.5 tag should be added (i am not quite sure what you mean by VS2010 not supporting it, mine does...)

Comment: @H.B., my mistake... some XAML 2009 features are not supported, x:Reference is indeed supported

Comment: @H.B., actually I'm not sure why it works... according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) it shouldn't, at least not in markup-compiled XAML (read the last paragraph)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Do you know what markup-compiled XAML is supposed to be?

Comment: @H.B., basically any XAML that is compiled to BAML (e.g. windows, user controls or resource dictionaries)

Comment: Took me some time on work on it again and then I forgot the part with `ElementName=` in the binding. But this is totally correct and works like I wanted! Thx!